# How to detect support for style's "scoped" attribute

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a recommend test for determining whether the user's browser supports the "scoped" attribute on "style" elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a recommended test, but I just wrote one, and I'll recommend it

```
var is_scoped = (function(s) {
    s.setAttribute('scoped', 'true');
    return !!s.scoped;
})(document.createElement('style'));
```

to be used as

```
if ( is_scoped ) {
    // scoped styles are supported
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fFaD7/4/)

currently scoped styles is only supported in the latest Firefox.

Written a little more verbose, it's easier to see what's going on

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.setAttribute('scoped', 'true');
var is_scoped = style.scoped === true;
```

We create a style tag and set the scoped *attribute* to true.
In browsers that supports scope, that also sets the underlying scope property, so `style.scope` would be `true` in supporting browsers, it non-supporting browsers it would be `undefined`.

This is the usual way of checking for support for a multitude of features, and it works just as well with `scoped`.

Comment: thats is possibly the best intro line i've ever seen. well.played.@adeneo.....golf clap.

Comment: @albert - well, it's true. I searched and I couldn't find much, so I wrote a test, and I do of course recommend it, no golf clap needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this..

```
var is_scoped = (function(s) {
    return 'scoped' in s;
})(document.createElement('style'));
```